# how i can take backup of file on UNIX-AIX?

Tags: unix, command-line, backup, aix

how i can take backup of file on UNIX-AIX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean. Backing up a file could be as simple as copying it somewhere else.

```
cp myfile /my/backups/myfile.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

[rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) should help. There are many [examples](http://www.samba.org/rsync/examples.html).